# How to remove a common property from each array which is nested

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array like below: I want to remove origin: 0 property and add it value directly using Javascript es6 feature. How to remove same repeated property from a nested array.

```
const orginalData = {
  name: {
    origin: 0,
    value: 'christi'
  },
  location: {
    origin: 0,
    value: 'Blr'
  },
  address: {
    origin: 0,
    value: [{
        "streetAddress1": {
          "origin": 0,
          "value": '12th street'
        },
        "city1": {
          "origin": 0,
          "value": 'Maxwell'
        }
      },
      {
        "streetAddress2": {
          "origin": 0,
          "value": '10=]]]]]]]th street'
        },
        "city2": {
          "origin": 0,
          "value": 'Coxwell'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
const finalData = {
  name: 'christi',
  location: 'Blr',
  address: [{
      streetAddress1: '10th street',
      city1: 'Maxwell'
    },
    {
      streetAddress2: '12th street',
      city2: 'Coxwell'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: tried reduce() didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create generic function like this. [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of an object to remove a level of nesting and update with nested `value`. If `value` as an array, recursively call the function on each object using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and get an array of restructured objects. This will work for any level of nesting

```js
const orginalData={name:{origin:0,value:"christi"},location:{origin:0,value:"Blr"},address:{origin:0,value:[{streetAddress1:{origin:0,value:"12th street"},city1:{origin:0,value:"Maxwell"}},{streetAddress2:{origin:0,value:"10=]]]]]]]th street"},city2:{origin:0,value:"Coxwell"}}]}};

function restructure(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, { value }]) => {
    acc[k] = Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(restructure) : value;
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

const finalData = restructure(orginalData)

console.log(finalData)
```

Comment: Nice. My idea failed to use `reduce` and as a result was unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NodeJs you could use [omit-deep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/omit-deep) to remove any property you want, regardless of where it is within the object.

For example, this:

```
const omitDeep = require('omit-deep');

const data = {
  name: { origin: 0, value: 'christi' },
  location: { origin: 0, value: 'Blr' },
  address: {
    origin: 0,
    value: [
      { streetAddress1: { origin: 0, value: '12th street' }, city1: { origin: 0, value: 'Maxwell' } },
      { streetAddress2: { origin: 0, value: '10=]]]]]]]th street' }, city2: { origin: 0, value: 'Coxwell' } }
    ]
  }
};

const finalData = omitDeep(data, 'origin');
```

Produces this result:

```
{
  name: { value: 'christi' },
  location: { value: 'Blr' },
  address: {
    value: [
      { streetAddress1: { value: '12th street' }, city1: { value: 'Maxwell' } },
      { streetAddress2: { value: '10=]]]]]]]th street' }, city2: { value: 'Coxwell' } }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

first if you want to edit your data, it can't be a const, so change const by let or var.
second 
 you can use for loop to do that, you can juste write a function or add a function to JSON object

```
// first logique as global function
function keepKey(data, keep) {
    for(let key in data) data[key] = data[key][keep];
}

// second logique as global function
function removeKey(data, remove, assignRest) {
    for(let key in data){
        //get the item
        let item = data[key];

        if(typeof item === 'object'){
            //if you put 'use strict' at the top you have to use a loop
                let temp = {}, lastKey = '';
                for(let itemKey in item){
                    if(itemKey !== remove){
                        if(assignRest === true) temp = item[itemKey];
                        else temp[itemKey] = item[itemKey];
                    }
                }
                data[key] = temp;

            //else you can use directly delete
                //delete item[remove];
        }
    }
}


// add the function to JSON object
JSON.keepKey = {...function...}
// or
JSON.removeKey = {...function...}


JSON.keepKey(orginalData, 'value');
// will give you 
{name: 'christi',location: 'Blr',...}


JSON.removeKey(orginalData, 'value', true);
// will give you 
{name: 'christi',location: 'Blr',...}


JSON.removeKey(orginalData, 'value', false);
// will give you 
{name: {value : 'christi'},location: {value: 'Blr'},...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const finalData = {
  // ...originalData, uncommnent this if you have more originalData has props that you do not want to chnage.
  name: originalData.name.value,
  location: originalData.location.value,
  address: originalData.address.value.map(item => {
    const { origin, ...rest } = item;

    return rest;
  }),
};
```

Comment: if there array is too long, how to use a loop instead of writing one by one

Comment: Do you have sample data and the a sample result? Is your originalData an arrray?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a copy of adiga's logic, made more explicit with extraneous identifiers and comments.

It's intended to help with understanding of the `reduce` method (and other JavaScript features) and of recursion.

```js
const originalData = {
  name: { origin: 0, value: 'christi' },
  location: { origin: 0, value: 'Blr' },
  address: {
    origin: 0,
    value: [
      {
        "streetAddress1": { "origin": 0, "value": '12th street' },
        "city1": { "origin": 0, "value": 'Maxwell' }
      },
      {
        "streetAddress2": { "origin": 0, "value": '10=]]]]]]]th street' },
        "city2": { "origin": 0, "value": 'Coxwell' }
      }
    ]
  }
};

function restructure(obj) {

  // Whether `restructure` is called directly or recursively, it builds and returns 
  //   a new object.
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce( (acc, curr, ind, arr ) => {

    // Here, `entries` is a 2D array where each 'row' is a property and the two 
    //   'columns' are the property name and property value.
    // We identify them explicitly below and assume that that the property value 
    //   is an object with a subproperty called "value", which we also identify.
    const propKey = curr[0], propVal = curr[1], subpropVal = propVal["value"];

    // Logs the index (ie 'row' number) of the current property and its property name
    //console.log(ind, propKey);

    // Here, `acc` is the object we will return. We give `acc` a new property with 
    //   the same name as the current property. 
    // If the "value" subproperty of the current property holds an array, the new 
    //   property will hold an array of objects, each of which is a `restructure`d 
    //   version of an object from the source array. (This can happen many times,
    //   restructuring nested objects from many nested arrays.)
    // If not, the new property will have the same value as the "value" subproperty does
    acc[propKey] = Array.isArray(subpropVal) ? subpropVal.map(restructure) : subpropVal;

    // If this call to `restructure` was recursive, we will continue looping through 
    //   the array we are currently processing. 
    // If this was the original call, we're done and log our `finalData` to the console.
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

const finalData = restructure(originalData);

console.log(finalData);
```